# Count distinct where attribute is either of keys

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given this table:

```
create temp table stats (
name text, country text, age integer
)

insert into stats values 

('eric',    'se',   1),
('eric',    'dk',   4),
('johan',   'dk',   6),
('johan',   'uk',   7),
('johan',   'de',   3),
('dan', 'de',   3),
('dan', 'de',   3),
('dan', 'de',   4)
```

I want know the count of distinct name that has either the country or the age the same as the key.

```
country age count
se      1   1
de      3   2
de      4   3
dk      4   3
dk      6   2
uk      7   1
```

There are 3 distinct names that have either `country = dk` (eric, johan) or `age = 4` (eric,dan)

So my question is, what is the best way to write this query?

I have this solution but I find it very ugly!

```
with country as (
 select count(distinct name), country
 from stats
 group by country
),
age as (
 select count(distinct name), age
 from stats
 group by age
),
country_and_age as(
 select count(distinct name), age, country
 from stats
 group by age, country
)
select country, age, c.count+a.count-ca.count as count from country_and_age ca join age a using(age) join country c using(country)
```

Any better way?

Comment: You make things too complex here.

First write a query that satisfies your conditions, i.e. find all rowas that has either the country or the age the same as the key. Then done, add the aggregate function.

Comment: I do not know the query that satisfies my condition, and when I do I do not have the time to go through all the rows. I need to pre-calculate as much as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can join on the original table also:

```
SELECT
  s1.country,
  s1.age,
  COUNT(distinct s2.name)
FROM stats s1
JOIN stats s2 ON s1.country=s2.country OR s1.age=s2.age
GROUP by 1, 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Select distinct age and country from stats. For each record count how many distinct names you find in records matching country or age.

```
select
  country, 
  age,
  (
    select count(distinct name)
    from stats s 
    where s.country = t.country 
    or s.age = t.age
  ) as cnt
from (select distinct country, age from stats) t;
```

Comment: This is indeed much nicer, I have never really worked with sub-queries in the variable list like that. Cool solution!

Answer (score 0):

I do not like in-line queries personally, so I would do something like that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        *
FROM    ( SELECT    country ,
                    age ,
                    COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY country ) AS c_cnt ,
                    COUNT(*) OVER ( PARTITION BY age ) AS a_cnt
          FROM      stats
        ) a
WHERE   c_cnt > 0
        OR a_cnt > 0
```

I am not sure about Postgres performance but in SQL Server the "in-line" is ~3 times slower (73% vs 27%)